# Recover partition OR data

Tags: disk-management, hdd, live-installation

So I was installing Loki in a Macbook 6.1 (late 2009). All was fine until the formating part.

It wasn't a system failure only my own dumbassery; in the HDD there was this backup partition that I didn't want to touch but at the choice part I tried the formating with the LMV option since it looked a lot more simple than the tradicional way of choicing manually, wich I always do, the thing here is that in the warning window they show you how is going to be your future new HDD's partition, I wasn't happy since it deleted everything so went backwards and choose the manual choice but to my dissmise all the partitions where gone. I stopped the install since I didn't want to touch the HDD

So,is there any hope to recover the partition or even some data using the    Elementary live DVD?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is, you can use several tools, depending if this is your only machine, I used to have this question in my job all the time.

I suggest make a live CD of something such as elementary (I use gparted for it personally)

and use a tool called "testdisk" or "photorec" both have uses.

try to use testdisk as it can recover the whole partition. or individual files dependant on damage.